How to create a DWG file from an .XYZ file using Design Automation (Civil 3D)?
I am converting an .XYZ file to a DWG file using Forge Design Automation (Civil 3D).
I have successfully generated a .DWG file, but I encounter an issue with Civil 3D: When Surfaces have too many points, it generates an .mms file.
And I don't know how to retrieve the .mms file (if any) in Design Automation, and if I can retrieve that .mms file, can I display the .DWG + .mms file in Forge Viewer?
Here is some data in my .XYZ file
-76016.76417989045,-197520.07325136382,7.9
-76011.62222159361,-197520.11488669761,7.9
-76006.48026332351,-197520.15651921448,7.9
-76001.33830508012,-197520.1981489144,7.82
-75996.19634686343,-197520.23977579738,7.86
-75991.05438867352,-197520.2813998634,7.67
-75985.91243051029,-197520.32302111248,7.61
-75980.77047237378,-197520.3646395446,7.61
-75975.62851426401,-197520.4062551598,7.72
-75970.48655618093,-197520.447867958,7.53
-75965.34459812457,-197520.4894779393,7.7
-75960.20264009493,-197520.53108510366,7.73
-75955.06068209435,-197520.57268945102,7.56...

I found this link and it seems there is no solution to prevent the creation of the .mms file.
So I want to extract the .DWG and .mms files after Design Automation processes them, and then use those two files to convert to Forge Viewer. Is that possible?

If you need to view that in the Viewer, I would suggest simplifying it, as the Viewer does not recognize the MMS file (translation engine uses the ObjectEnabler). If you are creating a TIN Surface, you can simplify it, which means removing points that are needed within a threshold elevation change.
SurfaceSimplifyOptions simplifyOptions = new SurfaceSimplifyOptions(SurfaceSimplifyType.PointRemoval);
simplifyOptions.MaximumChangeInElevation = 0.0001;
simplifyOptions.UseMaximumChangeInElevation = true;
theSurface.SimplifySurface(simplifyOptions);



don't know how to retrieve the .mms file (if any) in Design Automation

Do you know the file name? If so, then you can make this an optional output argument (same as the dwg file but with the optional attribute).

if I can retrieve that .mms file, can I display the .DWG + .mms file in Forge Viewer

Yes, I think if you upload both the dwg and .mms file then the viewer will be able to handle it.

The .mms file seems to have been automatically generated by the AutoCAD Core Console, and I did not intend to export that file.
